# spark: schema change -- transform & filter a dataframe on a column if it exits; don't if it doesn't

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The data I work with had a schema change. For the resulting dataFrame, which combines the old and new data, a column I'd like to transform & filter on used to not exist in the old data. It's not populated by "null"s. I'd like to transform&filter on that column whenever possible, i.e. whenever the column exits, I'd like to transform&filter on it; for earlier data without such a column, I'll just keep every row.

The issue is that the following code results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, because earlier data does't have the "ip" column.

```
val filteredData = sqlContext.sql(
s"SELECT $fieldsString FROM data $filterTerm")
.withColumn("ip",firstIp($"ip"))
.filter("`ip` not in ('30.90.30.90', '70.80.70.80')")
.filter("`ip` not like '10.%'")
```

The "firstIp" function above is simply a udf that take the first IP address from an array; it's defined by `val firstIp = udf[String, String](_.split(",")(0))`. I don't want to split the data by schema into two parts -- those with the "ip" column and those without... But is my objective achievable without splitting the data that way?

Answer (score 0):

*This answer addresses the old version of the question, which was only asking for using `filter` on different schemas. Doesn't really make sense now that the question has changed entirely*.

You could simply check if the column exists:

```scala
// let's create some test data
case class SchemaA(host: String)
case class SchemaB(host: String, ip: String) 

val testDataA = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    SchemaA("localhost"),
    SchemaA("other")
)).toDF()
val testDataB = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    SchemaB("localhost", "127.0.0.1"),
    SchemaB("other", "192.168.0.1")
)).toDF()

def doSomething(df: DataFrame) {
  val filtered = if (df.columns.contains("ip")) {
    df.filter("ip  in ('127.0.0.1')")
  } else {
    df
  }
  // do whatever you want after filtering...
  filtered.select($"host").show()
}

doSomething(testDataA)
doSomething(testDataB)
```

Comment: Thanks @bluenote10! I edited my question. It wasn't clear enough. And possibly have been misleading.

Comment: The point is, I combined the old and new logs into one dataframe. The logs have different schema. Hence, the column that the old log doesn't have is now populated by "null"s. I think perhaps the withColumn(udf) is causing the java.lang.NullPointerException; or perhaps the filtering is.

Comment: @MichM: That's why it is a good idea to prepare a minimal example when asking a question. Your question then really becomes a question of handling missing values and not how to handle different schemas.